# Difference between GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4 and GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5 in OpenGL ES

Tags: opengl-es

Does anybody know the difference between GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4 and GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5 data types in OpenGL ES?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are both 16 bit textures.

When using 32 bit texture you have 8 bit for each of the color components plus 8 bit for alpha, maximum quality and alpha control, so 8888.

With 16 bit there's always a compromise, if you only need color and not alpha then use the 565. Why 565 ? Because 16 bits can't divide evenly by 3 and our eyes are better at seing in the green spectrum, so better quality by giving the leftover bit to green.
If you need alpha but your images don't use gradients in alpha use 5551, 5 bits for each color 1 bit for alpha.
If you image has some gradient alpha then you can can use 4444, 4 bits for each color and 4 bits for alpha.

4444 has the worst color quality but it retains some alpha to mix, I use this for my font textures, for example, lighter than 32 bit and since the fonts are monocromatic they fit well in 4 bits.

Comment: Well, I would argue if a 32bit texture is really maximum quality. It's actually also a just compromise. Sometimes I would rather like a floating point texture (and even that is just a compromise). But well, that's just a minor conceptual flaw and not an error.

Comment: Anything digital is a compromise :) In this case the 24 bit color is an attempt to approximate the maximum different colors an human eye can see.

Comment: Yes, but calling it "maximum quality and alpha control" sounds like the non plus ultra it definitely isn't.

Comment: For fonts, it is worth considering using GL_ALPHA textures; these use 1 byte per pixel (vs 2 bytes for the 4444 format), yet give double the accuracy of the alpha channel available in 4444. As your font is monocromatic you can just set the colour to OpenGL (glColor* etc), so double the visual accuracy and half the memory.

Answer (score 4):

I am not an OpenGL expert but :

GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4 stands for GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_R_G_B_A where each RGBA values can have a value of 4 bit each (well that is 2^4)

GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5 stands for GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_R_G_B. You can see that their is no Alpha value available here so that is a major difference. RGB values can also have greater values since they are 5 6 and 5 bits respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when using `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4` as type in a pixel specification command (`glTexImage2D` or `glReadPixels`), the data is assumed to be laid out in system memory as one 16bit value per-pixel, with individual components each taking up 4 consecutive bits. It can only be used with a format of `GL_RGBA`.

Whereas `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5` also assumes individual pixels as 16bit values, but with the red and blue components taking up 5 bits each and the green component having 6 bits (there is no alpha channel). It can only be used with a format of `GL_RGB`.